# What is the difference between "bracket (mallocBytes n) free" and "allocaBytes"?

Tags: haskell, ffi

If you want background, see [here](https://github.com/xiph/flac/issues/24). In short, the question is: “What's actual difference between `bracket (mallocBytes n) free` and `allocaBytes` from [`Foreign.Marshall.Alloc`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html)”.

Normally in C, `alloca` allocates on stack and `malloc` allocates on heap. I'm not sure what's going on with it in Haskell, but I would not expect a difference between the above-mentioned equations other than speed. If you clicked the background link though, you know that with compiled code `bracket (mallocBytes n) free` was resulting in “double free or corruption” while `allocaBytes` works fine (the problem is not visible when in GHCi at all, everything works fine in both cases).

By now I've spent two days in painful debugging and I'm pretty confident that `bracket (mallocBytes n) free` was unstable somehow and the rest of the code is reliable. I'd like to find out what's the deal with `bracket (mallocBytes n) free`.

Comment: Is it possible that the buffer is being overrun in *both* situations, and it's just that `mallocBytes` and `free` catch the error while the other leads to silent corruption?  It appears that `allocaBytes` ultimately uses the GHC primitive `newPinnedByteArray#`, so it doesn't seem to be a simple `malloc` call.

Comment: I don't think the buffer is being overrun at all. I have tests now that confirm via encoding/decoding and comparing of WAVE data blocks that encoder and decoder bindings work correctly and decoded back data matches the original. If the buffer were overrun, it would likely lead to data corruption.

Comment: Not necessarily. "Undefined behaviour" is, well, undefined. It might work, it might also set your cat on fire. Note that a double use of `free` usually shows memory corruption, not necessarily a real second use of `free` at that memory location.

Comment: @Zeta, I thought of this possibility when I began investigation of issue. Certainly max_frame_size * block_align should be enough to hold one frame. It's a bit trickier with assigning 24 bit samples, but the issue was there even for 16 bit samples and even when I allocated much more memory than needed to test if buffer overrun is taking place. Even with extra memory the issue was there.

Comment: Do you have a way to duplicate the problem?  If I grab your current head at commit `0bac08`, replace the `allocaBytes bufferSize` call with `bracket (mallocBytes bufferSize) free` in `StreamDecoder.hs` and run `stack test`, the test suite runs fine.  (I am running on an Ubuntu Xenial distribution with libflac 1.3.1-4.)

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Sure thing, you need `encoder-decoder-tests` branch, it has the tests that cause the crash. Just checkout that branch, replace `allocaBytes` like you did and run the tests.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`bracket (mallocBytes size) free` will use C's `malloc` and `free`, whereas `allocaBytes size` will use memory that's managed by GHCs garbage collection. That in itself is a huge difference already, since the `Ptr` of `allocaBytes` might be surrounded by unused (but allocated) memory:

```
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Foreign.Marshal.Alloc
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.Storable

-- Write a value at an invalid pointer location
hammer :: Ptr Int -> IO ()
hammer ptr = pokeElemOff ptr (-1) 0 >> putStrLn "hammered"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Hammer time! Alloca!"
  forM_ [1..10] $ \n ->
    print n >> allocaBytes 10 hammer

  putStrLn "Hammer time! Bracket"
  forM_ [1..10] $ \n ->
    print n >> bracket (mallocBytes 10) free hammer
```

Result:

```
Hammer time! Alloca!
1
hammered
2
hammered
3
hammered
4
hammered
5
hammered
6
hammered
7
hammered
8
hammered
9
hammered
10
hammered
Hammer time! Bracket
1
hammered
<program crashes>
```

As you can see, although we've used `arr[-1] = 0`, `allocaBytes` happily ignored that error. However, `free` will (often) blow up in your face if you write to position `-1`. It will also blow up in your face if there has been a memory corruption on another allocated memory region*.

Also, with `allocaBytes`, it's likely that the pointer points somewhere into already allocated memory, not to the start of one, e.g.

```
nursery = malloc(NURSERY_SIZE);

// ...

pointer_for_user = nursery + 180;

// pointer_for_user[-1] = 0 is not as 
// much as a problem, since it doesn't yield undefined behaviour
```

What does that mean? Well, `allocaBytes` is less likely to blow up in your face, but at the cost that you don't notice if your C-code variant would lead to memory corruption. Even worse, as soon as you write outside of the bounds returned by `allocaBytes`, your possibly corrupting other *Haskell* values silently.

However, we're talking here about undefined behaviour. The code above may or may not crash on your system. It may also crash in the `allocaBytes` part.

If I were you, I would [trace the `malloc` and `free` calls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mtrace.3.html).

---

<sup>* I once had a "double use of free" error in the middle of my program. Debugged everything, rewrote most of the "bad" routine. Unfortunately, the error vanished in debug builds, but recurred in release builds. It turned out that in the first ten lines of `main`, I accidentally wrote to `b[i - 1]` with `i = 0`.</sup>

Comment: You were right, I mixed up frame sizes and block sizes, and since block size is often greater than frame size there was quite a few bytes written over the boundary of the buffer.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to duplicate the problem, and I can confirm that there is substantial buffer overrun going on.  If you use the following allocator (please excuse the quick and dirty code) which adds a page's worth of `0xa5`s after the buffer and dumps it out if it's modified, you can see overrun of several hundred bytes in several tests:

```
withBuffer :: Int -> (Ptr a -> IO b) -> IO b
withBuffer n = bracket begin end
  where begin = do
          a <- mallocBytes (n + 4096)
          mapM_ (\i -> pokeByteOff (a `plusPtr` n) i (0xa5 :: Word8)) [0..4095]
          return a
        end = \a -> do
          page <- mapM (\i -> peekByteOff (a `plusPtr` n) i) [0..4095]
          when (any (/= (0xa5 :: Word8)) page) $ do
            putStrLn $ unlines $ map (hexline page) [0,16..4095]
            error "corruption detected"
          free a
        hexline bytes off = unwords . map hex . take 16 . drop off $ bytes
        hex = printf "%02x"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I know where to look now ;-)

Comment: Ah, a good old canary. By the way, I would change the wording, since your code doesn't "add a page" (the additional memory might not start at the page alignment). Also, you can simplify `hexline` to `hexline bytes off = unwords . map hex . take 16 . drop off $ bytes`.